# Html printed page resolution (or size in pixels)

Tags: html, css, printing, resolution

Does anybody know what is the resolution that will be used to render a printed HTML page. I'd like to know what size (in centimeters or inches) will be a printed image of say 500x500pixels. I know this value will change if I set the zoom value (IE and FF), but I am interested in the default value (when zoom is at 100%).

Also, is there any way of controlling this resolution from CSS?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

either 72ppi or 96ppi, depending on combination of OS/browser. Margins are an issue too.

If this is for a site with login users, get them to set their resolution, or try to guess from the browser. Remember that anyone can change this setting on their computer.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can control the size, but not the resolution, of the printed page. Relevant units of size, for print css, would include

- Centimetres (cm)
- Millimetres (mm)
- Points (pt)
- Pica (pc)
- Inches (in)
- M (em)
- X (ex)

Comment: For print? I'm honestly not sure; but I don't think that pixels are transferable to a medium that doesn't use pixels. I realise that print-media does use such measurements as ppi (pixels per inch) in discussion of printer-capabilities, but directly relevant? I'm not saying they're *not* relevant, just that I've never used them, nor *see* that they're useful in the medium. Experience and anecdote may teach me otherwise, though...

Answer (score 0):

The calculation is simple:

With 96dpi you need to multiply 96 to the width and height in inches (1in = 96dpi).
For example, A4 (8.5in x 11in) will be printed with 96dpi:
96 * 8.5 = 816,
96 * 11 = 1056.
The resolution of the A4 96dpi page is 816px x 1056px.